# "Application tried to present modally an active controller"?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I just came across a crash showing a `NSInvalidArgumentException` with this message on an app which wasn't doing this before.

> Application tried to present modally an active controller
>   UITabBarController: 0x83d7f00.

I have a `UITabBarController` which I create in the `AppDelegate` and give it the array of `UIViewControllers`.

One of them I want to present modally when tapped on it. I did that by implementing the delegate method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

If that view controller is of the class of the one I want to present modally, I return NO and do

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

And now I'm getting that error, which seems to mean that you can't present modally a view controller that is active somewhere else (in the tabbar...)
I should say I'm on XCode 4.2 Developer Preview 7, so this is iOS 5 (I know about the NDA, but I think I'm not giving any forbidden details). I currently don't have an XCode installation to test if this crashes compiling against the iOS4 SDK, but I'm almost entirely sure it doesn't.

I only wanted to ask if anyone has experienced this issue or has any suggestion

Comment: Prior to iOS 5, this did not raise an exception, but returned nothing.
From iOS 5 on, this command raises an exception.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Assume you have three view controllers instantiated like so:

```
UIViewController* vc1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController* vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
UIViewController* vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
```

You have added them to a tab bar like this:

```
UITabBarController* tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, nil]];
```

Now you are trying to do something like this:

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:vc3];
```

This will give you an error because that Tab Bar Controller has a death grip on the view controller that you gave it.  You can either not add it to the array of view controllers on the tab bar, or you can not present it modally.

Apple expects you to treat their UI elements in a certain way.  This is probably buried in the Human Interface Guidelines somewhere as a "don't do this because we aren't expecting you to ever want to do this".

Comment: The thing is this was absolutely no problem prior to iOS 5, hence my concern! What I did was to add a dummy UIViewController to the tabbar and present modally the actual view controller subclass instance.

Comment: @Iswank, now in iOS 6, to make things "easier," they deprecated presentModalViewController causing all kinds of rotational problems...you need to use presentViewController: animated: completion and check how your app is handling the changes

Comment: what if need to present exactly from "selected controller"? I mean to leave tabor visible

Answer (score 16):

I have the same problem. I try to present view controller just after dismissing.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

When I try to do it without animation it works perfectly so the problem is that controller is still alive. I think that the best solution is to use `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` for iOS5

Comment: It fails if you dismiss it animated because by the time you want to present the modal view controller again, it is still modally on the screen, being animated away.

Comment: It is depricated in IOS 6.0

Answer (score 16):

In my case i was trying to present the viewController (i have the reference of the viewController in the TabBarViewController) from different view controllers and it was crashing with the above message.
In that case to avoid presenting you can use

> viewController.isBeingPresented

```
!viewController.isBeingPresented {
          // Present your ViewController only if its not present to the user currently.
}
```

Might help someone.

Comment: it is working only in viewWillappperar but when  i have check it before presenting viewController which is already presented, it is always return false.

Comment: Not working for me. Still gets app crash. 
(!viewController.presentingViewController) resolved problem.

Answer (score 7):

The same problem error happened to me when I tried to `present` a child view controller instead of its `UINavigationViewController` parent

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem.I solve it. You can try This code:

```
[tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 3):

For React Native Developer - Problem might not be in AppDelegate Or main.m if app has been successfully build and is running and will crash after splash or perhaps the error screen

Issue might be due to use of fonts/resources that is not available with xcode and not properly configured.. You can find out the error by commenting certain portion starting from App.js and drilling inside the navigation/screens and commenting the components till you find the component that is generating the error....

In my case the resource of fontFamily was making an issue which was used right after splash in walkthrough screen

```
<Text style={{fontFamily: Fonts.roboto}}>ABC</Text>
```

Here font roboto wasnot configured properly. Wasted entire days just debugging the error hope its helps you

Answer (score 2):

For React Native developers: answer give by @rahul-shakya was not the reason for my.

We were using `react-native-loading-spinner-overlay` (we will call it `Spinner`) to show the progress bar, which internally uses `Modal` when we were transitioning from one screen to another we were not hiding the `Spinner` that lead to this issue.

Just hiding the `Spinner` & giving some delay before navigation it worked.

So in general if our code is trying to show one `modal` over other then we get into such issues, in `react-native` it is quite hard to find as we will have to see the lib code to understand if that is using `modal`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was presenting the `rootViewController` of an `UINavigationController` when I was supposed to present the `UINavigationController` itself.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
[tabBarController presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

and keep

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: this gives deprecated warning...so what is alternativ of this?

Comment: Here I used  [blockSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
self.present(viewControllerToPresent: UIViewController, animated: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)?)
```

you can use:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my way **which supporting multiple** Windows(from a single APP) on the iPad and **nested** modal present.

```
import UIKit

///✅Use this public method
public func SheetViewController(ViewController:UIViewController) {
    
    for i in returnAvailableViewControllers().shuffled() {
        if i.presentedViewController == nil && !ViewController.isViewLoaded {i.present(ViewController, animated: true, completion:  {})}
    }
}

///Returns all possible ViewControllers
private func returnAvailableViewControllers() -> [UIViewController] {
    let 场景 = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
    
    var 存储VC : [UIViewController] = []

    for i in 场景 {
        
        if i.activationState == .foregroundActive {
            //⭐️Set up “foregroundActive” to give the user more control
            var 视图控制器 = (i.delegate as? UIWindowSceneDelegate)?.window??.rootViewController
            
            if 视图控制器 != nil {
                存储VC.append(视图控制器!)
            }
            
            
            
            var 结束没 = true
            while 结束没 {
                //Enumerate all child ViewController
                视图控制器 = 视图控制器?.presentedViewController
                if 视图控制器 != nil {
                    存储VC.append(视图控制器!)
                } else {
                    结束没.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    return 存储VC
}
```