# Application tried to present modally an active controller ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, modalviewcontroller, viewcontroller

I was trying to set the ViewController with a parent view controller before it shows show that it can provide call backs, I done this using `PrepareForSegue`

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"newQuarter"])
    {
        [segue.destinationViewController setParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

It crashed giving me the error message: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller.`

So I tried using another method and set up a new view controller on the button touches up,

```
- (IBAction) buttonClicked
{
    NewViewController *newController = [[NewViewController alloc] init];
    [newController setParentViewController:self];

    [self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

but with no luck it is still giving me the same error message, can anyone please advice? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Application tried to present modally an active controller"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429014/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller)

Comment: @CarlVeazey this is not a duplicate of "Application tried to present modally an active controller". Thank you for suggesting though! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved the problem, since the parent view controller is a `tableViewController`, which it was embedded in a `navigationViewController`. That's why the segue should be pushed rather then performing modal transition.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and Matthew's explanation seems correct.

Replace:

```
[self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
[self presentViewController:newController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

will perform a MODAL segue, which is what gives the error.

Using this line *instead*:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
```

performs a segue by 'PUSHING' a new view controller onto the Navigation Controller stack (in XCode 6 and above, this is the same thing as defining a segue type of 'show' on the storyboard). This is why you need this when you're using a Navigation Controller.