# Failing to show UIAlertController due to - '''Application tried to present modally an active controller'

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have an application that displays documents in a `UICollectionView`. Each `UICollectionViewCell` has a button (distinct from that carried out by `didSelectItemAt`). This button brings up a custom popup which I have created using a `UIViewController`. It is presented `Over Current Context`. This popup presents a list of options, one including `Delete document`. When a user selects this latter option, I would like a `UIAlertController` to appear to confirm delete.  This is the issue that I am facing.

Here is my code:

The error that I am getting is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',
>   reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller
>   .

**CUSTOM POPUP (UIViewController)**

```
protocol DismissOptionShowDeleteAlert {
    func showDeleteAlert()
}

class MoreOptionsOnPDFViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

var showDeleteAlertDelegate: DismissOptionShowDeleteAlert!

/ TAP ON ROW
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){

    ...

     }else if indexPath == [0,4]{ // DELETE DOCUMENT

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.dismiss(animated: true) {
                self.showDeleteAlertDelegate.showDeleteAlert()
            }
        }
    }

    ...

}
```

**UICollectionView:**

```
class CollectionViewFolder: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MoreInfoDocument, MoveFolder, ScanObjectMovedFolder, DismissOptionShowDeleteAlert{

// SHOW DELETE CONFIRMATION ALERT
func showDeleteAlert() {

    Alerts.deleteDocumentConfirm(on: self) {
        // DELETE DOCUMENT FROM SERVER
        print("Delete document ...")
    }
}

}
```

**UIAlertController Struct:**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct Alerts {
private static func showBasicAlert(on vc: UIViewController, with title: String, message: String, action: @escaping (() -> ())){

    let alert =  UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default) { (UIActionAlert) in

        action()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        vc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


static func deleteDocumentConfirm(on vc: UIViewController, action: @escaping (() -> ())){
    showBasicAlert(on: vc, with: "Please Confirm Delete", message: "", action: action)
}

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Application tried to present modally an active controller"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429014/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is exactly what your error says. You seem to be presenting the view controller `vc` instead of the `alert` from `vc`

```
private static func showBasicAlert(on vc: UIViewController, with title: String, message: String, action: @escaping (() -> ())){

    let alert =  UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default) { (UIActionAlert) in

        action()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil) // You should be presenting the alert here.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are presenting wrong. You need to present alert not vc.

Replace below with your code.

```
struct Alerts {
private static func showBasicAlert(on vc: UIViewController, with title: String, message: String, action: @escaping (() -> ())){

    let alert =  UIAlertController.init(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "OK", style: .default) { (UIActionAlert) in

        action()
    }

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction.init(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

    alert.addAction(okAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace below line

`vc.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)`

to

`vc.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`