# How to detect if user STOPPED shaking the phone in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to know when the user stopped shaking and when he does, I would like to dismiss the alertViewController. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

I've tried both using methods motionEnded and motionBegan.

Here is my code. I want to dismiss the alertViewController when the user stops shaking the phone.

```
       let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:
        "Shaking", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

    override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if motion == .motionShake {
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }

    override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if alertController.isBeingPresented {
            alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

Comment: `motionEnded` should do the job. Why hasn't it worked?

Comment: but how do I hide alertController in `motionEnded`?

Comment: Make `alertController` a property, so that you can access it in both methods.

Comment: @Sweeper can you write down the code please?

Comment: AtulParmar has already written what I meant in his answer.

Comment: @Sweeper please take a look at my updated code. It throws SIGBRT when I stop shaking and shake again.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method for ended motion, See this post for more info https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621090-motionended

declare `alertController` outside of delegate method.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message:
    "Shaking", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

override func motionBegan(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake && !alertController.isBeingPresented {
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}

override func motionEnded(_ motion: UIEvent.EventSubtype, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .motionShake {
         alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Works. But after a while it throws SIGBRT saying `Application tried to present modally an active controller <Shake_Gesture_app.ViewController: 0x10217d350>.`

Comment: see the following post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429014/application-tried-to-present-modally-an-active-controller

Comment: use ".isBeingPresented" and  ".isBeingDismissed" property to check 'alertController' os open or not and do needfull accordingly.

Comment: put condition on present alertcontroller.

Comment: Tried your code. throws the same Error and the alertController is not being dismissed. Already tried condition `alertController.isBeingPreseneted` in `motionEnded`