# React native - Application tried to present modally a view controller

Tags: ios, react-native

I got this error when i try to build ios.

Thread 1: "Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x7f9e930adc80> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x7f9e9330d480>."

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
#if defined(FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED) && __has_include(<FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>)
  InitializeFlipper(application);
#endif
  
  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can checkout my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75809045/1992811)

adding stuff here for ease,

We were using `react-native-loading-spinner-overlay` (we will call it `Spinner`) to show the progress bar, which internally uses `Modal` when we were transitioning from one screen to another we were not hiding the `Spinner` that lead to this issue.

Just hiding the `Spinner` & giving some delay before navigation it worked.

So in general if our code is trying to show one `modal` over other then we get into such issues, in `react-native` it is quite hard to find as we will have to see the lib code to understand if that is using `modal`.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you already are presenting **ViewController**.
First Try to **dismiss** that ViewController and then **present** it.

Comment: Tried not working.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a modal you should close modal then navigate, I handle it using setTimeout